# VPN config with QR

Tags: vpn, macos

I know you can create a QR for WiFi to share around with friends and family so I was wondering if you could do the same with vpn configuration. I google around and got no where,but this seems to be the right place to ask.

Comment: Isn‘t this something the provider of the VPN solution you are using might offer?

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible if you create a VPN profile and either turn it into a QR code or upload it to a server and provide the url to it as a QR code.

When the QR code is scanned, the profile should be recognized and its import offered.

Comment: Why has my answer been downvoted? Not detailed enough?